# Duplicate Entry Insertion while insertion of DataTable in Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm inserting `DataTable` in Database using `StoredProcedure` but the issue is, its inserting twice the actual number of entries of `DataTable` to be inserted, the procedure is below, kindly guide me, if I'm using wrong approach, why its duplicating the rows? The return which is required is working fine.
Thanks In Advance

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_InsertStore_Recvry]
(@dt_Recovery Recovery_Store READONLY)

AS
Declare @RecoveryIDs as Table (IDs int, ClientIds int)
declare @StoreID int
declare @ClientID int
declare @Arrears decimal(18, 2)
declare @NetDues decimal(18, 2)
declare @Received decimal(18, 2)
Declare @RecoveryRecID int

begin
select * into #tempTable from @dt_Recovery

declare @Count int
set @Count= (select COUNT(*) from #tempTable)

while(@Count > 0)
begin

set @Count = @Count-1
set @ClientID = (Select top 1 ClientID from #tempTable)
set @StoredID = (Select top 1 StoredID from #tempTable where ClientID=@ClientID)
set @Arrears = (Select top 1 Arrears from #tempTable where ClientID=@ClientID)
set @NetDues = (Select top 1 NDues from #tempTable where ClientID=@ClientID)
set @Received = (Select top 1 Received from #tempTable where ClientID=@ClientID)

Insert into tblRecovery (StoreID,  ClientID, Arrears, NetDues, Received)
values (@StoreID,@ClientID,@Arrears,@NetDues,@Received)

select @RecoveryID = Scope_Identity()

insert into @RecoveryIDs (IDs,ClientIds) values (@RecoveryID, @ClientID )

delete from #tempTable where ClientID=@ClientID

end
Select * from @RecoveryIDs
```

Comment: Arent you simply executing the SP twice from code?

Comment: please show us, how you are calling that Sproc from your asp.net application

Comment: Are you mean `@RecoveryIDs` is the data table, or you're filling `DataTable` in code behind? Please explain how you're executing the procedure from page's code-behind.

Comment: I tried to paste code here in comments but it exceeds the max character  limit...can you please ping me through Skype/Teamviewer.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using SQL Server. If yes then why are you using a while-loop to insert values into a table and return the inserted Ids? 
The same can be accomplished in a far better way via the OUTPUT clause:
[OUTPUT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Example:

```
INSERT INTO tblRecovery(StoreID,  ClientID, Arrears, NetDues, Received) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.CLientId INTO @RecoveryIDs(IDs, ClientIds) SELECT StoredID, ClientID, Arrears, NDues, Received FROM #tempTable
```

Aside from that there seems to be no issue with your SQL code. So could you post the .NET code as well?

Comment: I think you didn't read the question carefully actually i'm inserting table and returning the PK of the entries inserted in this session of stored procedure.
Or may be i'm going wrong, could you please tell me where it will return all the inserted id's of table (that are added right now).
as i mentioned that i'm inserting table with different no of rows, so the case is its insert the row but twice the no of row that should be inserted... can you please ping me through Skype/Teamviewer.